# UI designer in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, qt, user-interface, eclipse-cdt

I want to design a GUI for c++, i am using eclipse JUNO CDT (x64) , do you know another plugin than QT plugin ? or ares there a win64 QT version ?

Comment: Netbeans works better for GUI design,,,, you may try using that

Comment: Do you need to use Qt?  Is it only for a single platform?  Are you require a particular license?  Your question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to install QtSDK which includes QtCreator, designer, assistant, linguist ..etc.
You can create your new Qt project with QtCreator which creates the .pro file and form files. You can design your .ui(form) files with designer and then open your project as a Makefile project in Eclipse CDT which is a better IDE than QtCreator.

http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-SDK/

Comment: Have you tried this? Do you know how Eclipse CDT indexer plays along with the Qt C++ extensions? Eclipse CDT is not fun unless the indexer and the syntax checking works...

Comment: Yes in fact, it is a little bit problematic. If the platform is going to be windows, visual studio might be a better choice than Eclipse CDT for Qt projects. It has a Qt plugin I guess but still Qt designer is necessary for UI design.

Comment: I prefer to develop in Linux, regardless of the target platform. But I  guess the sensible thing is to use Qt Creator for the GUI related code  and keep the internal logic in a separate project. This would also enforce a better architecture anyway.